# Optimal realization of cleaning the names function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I wanted to ask you about the best function performance.
I have a function for cleaning names which runs through pandas data frame column where each element is a long string. Function check if string starts with something return x, if str contain something return y, etc.
I have like tons of such conditions (20-30 elifs) with different regex cleaning constructions (each regex depends on how the name is look like):

```
def lets_make_a_short_name(row):
    name = row['name']
    short_name =0
    if name.startswith('something'): short_name = 'something'
    elif (name.startswith('something') or name.startswith('something')):
          short_name = re.search('(?<=_)[^_]+(?=_)',name).group()
    ....
    else: short_name = 'something'
return short_name
```

What will give me the best performance:

- if-elif-else construction
- case switcher
- or like here in the article https://towardsdatascience.com/the-ultimate-guide-for-column-creation-with-pandas-dataframes-83b8c565110e method of multiple conditions (vectorized solution)

```
conditions = [df['bruto'] / df['age'] > 100, 
(df['bruto'] / df['age'] <= 100) & (df['bruto'] / df['age'] > 50), (df['bruto'] / df['age'] < 50) & 
(df['bruto'] / df['age'] > 0)]
outputs = ['high salary', 'medium salary', 'low salary']
df['salary_age_relation'] = np.select(conditions, outputs, 'no salary')
```

- or maybe something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without knowing all of your conditions and results it's hard to give advice. 20-30 conditions seems a bit extreme though?

Comment: I agree with the comment above but I think in general using something like a dictionary as a case switcher will beat out if else statements

Answer (score 0):

To simulate a switch-statement, I usually define a helper function like this:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c: v in c
```

which can be used with a one pass for-loop:

```
x = 3
for case in switch(x):
    if case(1): print("once"); break
    if case(2): print("twice"); break
else: print(x,"times")
```

A variant of this could be defined to match on regular expressions instead of merely finding the value in a list:

```
def reSwitch(v): yield lambda *c: any(re.match(p,v) for p in c)
```

You could then write your code like this:

```
for case in reSwitch(name):

    if case("^something"): 
        short_name = 'something'
        break

    if case("^something","something$"):
        short_name = re.search('(?<=_)[^_]+(?=_)',name).group()
        break
    ...
else: short_name = 'something'
```

This would not make your code any shorter but it would certainly be more legible and maintainable.